# Script to create multiple update and SELECT statements

Tags: postgresql, shell

We have 2 tables renewal_bkp and adhoc_bkp and 1 MV as test_mv1.
I basically want to create a script that will update one row of renewal_bkp and adhoc_bkp and then select the data from the above MV.
This needs to be done in a loop fashion. Below is an

example:

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
update renewal_bkp set network_status='provisioned' where msisdn='3234561010240';
update adhoc_bkp set status='provisioned' where msisdn='3234561010240';
select * from test_mv1 where msisdn='3234561010240';
...
...
and so on
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

This same statement needs to get generated 1000 times with different msisdn numbers.
Can you help me to create a script to do so, then manually writing down each statements.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Not yet.. I was doing manually but this takes too much time when we have huge no of msisdn's. Any script logic will be hhelpful

Comment: Any help please on this?

Comment: For efficiency, generate a temporary table with the numbers in it, then run three SQL statements that join with that table. If efficiently is not so important, write a simple loop in shell that generates all the statements.

Comment: Can you  help with the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Although it is totally unclear how you are accessing the `msisdn`s, here is a compact version that does all three things in one batch, atomic, with the help of [Data-Modifying CTE's](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```sql
WITH
    ids (id) AS (
        VALUES ('3234561010240'), ('...'), ...
    ),
    renewals AS (
        UPDATE renewal_bkp SET network_status = 'provisioned'
        WHERE msisdn IN (SELECT id FROM ids)
    ),
    adhoc AS (
        UPDATE adhoc_bkp SET status = 'provisioned'
        WHERE msisdn IN (SELECT id FROM ids)
    )
SELECT *
FROM test_mv1
WHERE msisdn IN (SELECT id FROM ids)
```

Instead of the `VALUES` clause, you can also put a regular `SELECT` from a dedicated table, which would make sense if you're going to execute this more often than once or twice a year.